# Column ambiguously defined when using select for update

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have some sql statement:

```
 SELECT *         
 FROM OSOBA o          
 LEFT JOIN DOKLAD d on d.ID_OSOBA = o.ID_OSOBA     
 WHERE o.AIFO like '2D5C%'  
   AND o.PLATNOST = 0

 SELECT *
 FROM OSOBA o          
 WHERE o.AIFO like '2D5C%'
   AND o.PLATNOST = 0     
 FOR UPDATE OF o.ID_OSOBA


SELECT * 
FROM OSOBA o
LEFT JOIN DOKLAD d on d.ID_OSOBA = o.ID_OSOBA       
WHERE o.AIFO like '2D5C%'
  AND o.PLATNOST = 0 
FOR UPDATE OF o.ID_OSOBA
```

first and second statements are OK. But in last I got ora-00918. I have no idea why. In FOR UPDATE I defined prefix of table please help

Comment: :Try SELECT o.*,d.*  in the last query ,but i think your ways it should work ,because you have given alias for both table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2316477) thread appears to be saying that there is an oracle bug using for update of and joins that is fixed in version 11.2.0.2.

Comment: hm and what about some solution how to fix it in this version ?

Comment: To make the above sql statement work you would need to upgrade, unless there is a patch. If you explained a bit more about what you are trying to do possibly someone could suggest a workaround.